# Finding lines which are greater than 120 characters length using sed

Tags: sed

I want to get a list of lines in a batch file which are greater than 120 characters length. For this I thought of using sed. I tried but I was not successful. How can i achieve this ? 
Is there any other way to get a list other than using sed ?? 
Thanks..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another way to do this using awk:

```
cat file | awk 'length($0) > 120'
```

Comment: awk 'length($0) > 120 { print NR ":" $0 }'

Comment: @choroba no particular reason. It will work without it, filtering standard input

Comment: How do I do less than? `<` doesn't work

Answer (score 23):

You can use `grep` and its repetition quantifier:

```
grep '.\{121\}' script.sh
```

Comment: `grep` is at least 10x faster on large files (10Gb).

Comment: @choroba I tried this `grep '.\{120\}' script.sh` code, it print the **whole file** and just colorize lines that exceed a 120 chars length. Is there way print only lines that exceed a certain length, with line numbers?

Comment: @minto: What version of grep, what OS?

Comment: @choroba grep (GNU grep) 2.25, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Weird, can't reproduce on Ubuntu 18.04 nor 14.04.

Comment: @minto: Do you have $GREP_OPTIONS set?

Comment: @minto To show line numbers, include the `-n` flag with grep.

Comment: For me, this seems to output all lines with length *at least* 120. I replaced 120 with 121 to catch all lines with length greater than 120.

Comment: @ChristopherMiller: You're right, of course. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Using grep, is there a way to print lines shorter than 120 characters?

Comment: @Amol: Use `grep -v`.

Answer (score 12):

Using sed, you have some alternatives:

```
sed -e '/.\{120\}/!d'
sed -e '/^.\{,119\}$/d'
sed -ne '/.\{120\}/p'
```

The first option matches lines that don't have (at least) 120 characters (the `!` after the expression is to execute the command on lines that **don't** match the pattern before it), and deletes them (ie. doesn't print them).

The second option matches lines that from start (`^`) to end (`$`) have a total of characters from zero to 119. These lines are also deleted.

The third option is to use the `-n` flag, which tells sed to not print lines by default, and only print something if we tell it to. In this case, we match lines that have (at least) 120 characters, and use `p` to print them.

Comment: The question names `sed` specifically. While I appreciate all the other answers, this one is the only one that works when sed is all you have.