# How to determine number of contigs that are higher thank a specific size

Tags: grep, bioinformatics

I hope you're doing well

please i have a fasta file like

```
>contig1
sequence
>contig2
sequence
>contig3
>sequence
```

each sequence has it length 
i want to determine  number of contigs that are higher that 9000 ( so the length of sequence is higher than 9000 )

Thank you

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12815519) will get you started.

Comment: Yes but the sequences are  more than one line

Comment: You have to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't assume we can see your data, only you have access to it. We encourage questions with research, attempts, and, when needed (such as your case), a clear and minimal input file and expected output.

Comment: I see grep in the tag, is it a requirement of your question? or any Linux based can do? awk, sed? any languages python?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged grep, so `grep -c '.\{9000\}' your_fasta.fa` is probably the most straightforward method.

A more 'bioinformatics' approach is to use seqkit (https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/): `seqkit seq -m 9000 your_fasta.fa > newfile.txt` to extract the sequences over 9000 bases to 'newfile.txt', and `grep -c ">" newfile.txt` to count the number of sequences with length >9000.

Also, here are a bunch of awk/perl/bioawk solutions you can adapt: https://www.biostars.org/p/79202/

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task if you install [BioPerl module Bio::SeqIO](https://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live/blob/master/README.md). Then you can save the script below as count_contigs.pl in the same directory as file with contigs named "**contigs.fasta**" and run the script with `perl count_contigs.pl`. It will count contigs that are longer than 9000 bp from input file and print the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;    
use Bio::SeqIO;

# Setting minimum length to be more than 9000
my $min_len = 9000;

# Reading the input fasta file
my $seqio_in = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "contigs.fasta", 
                                     -format => "fasta" );
# Setting the counter
my $counter = 0; 

# Counting sequences if length > min_len     
while ( my $seq = $seqio_in->next_seq ) {
    if ( $seq->length  >  $min_len ) {
        $counter++;
    }
}

# Print the result
print "There are '$counter' sequences that are longer than $min_len\n";
```